# Why am I not able to see table contents from sqlite3 interface?

Tags: python, sqlite

I wrote a simple basic program to create a database and insert one row in a table. 
Here is how the program looks like.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print "Opened database successfully";

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE COMPANY
   (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL);''')

print "Table created successfully";

curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE) \
  VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32)");

cursor = conn.execute("SELECT id, name, age from COMPANY")
for row in cursor:
    print "ID = ", row[0]
    print "NAME = ", row[1]
    print "AGE = ", row[2], "\n"
conn.close()
```

The above program successfully creates a database(test.db) and a table(COMPANY). 
It even displays the data.

```
Problem :
```

The tuple is getting properly inserted in the table but when I try to open the table content from the sqlit3 interface, I get blank output.

```
root@root> sqlite3 test.db 
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
COMPANY
sqlite> select * from COMPANY;
sqlite>
```

Why is it so that I get the result if I run "SELECT" query through script but I get no output from sqlite3 interface ?? 
Am I missing something ?

P.S - ***Script is written in python.
Database is SQLite(version 3.8.2)***

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to commit.

```
# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()
```

You can also use the connection in a [`context manager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager), committing the results once the block exits:

```
with conn:
   conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE) VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32)");
```

or you can turn on `autocommit`, by setting the [`isolation_level`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level) to `None`:

```
conn.isolation_level = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not committed your changes.
Call `conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`.

Comment: My bad. I just missed out the commit. 
Thanks Fabricator, it worked like charm.